# Configure external jar lib in eclipse plugin not from lib folder but direct from target folder

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin

Actually I have a abc.jar file in a normal Java abc project perhaps in the same workspace I have to use the jar in Eclipse plugin project. The abc.jar keeps on changing & it would be sometime difficult to update in the lib folder of eclipse plugin project. Is there any way,abc.jar can be directly referenced from target folder of abc project and referenced in plugin MANIFEST.mf file instead of lib folder. Both of the projects are Maven projects

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `external:path-to-jar` as an entry in the Bundle-ClassPath but there is only very limited support for this.

Eclipse PDE does not support it so you will have to edit the MANIFEST.MF directly.

The path needs to be the absolute path to the jar which can be cause problems when running the code on different systems.

Because of these problems it is generally recommended that you don't use this feature.